# Chatter Feed Item: PDF Preview not working

Tags: pdf, chatter-feed

I have created a feed item through apex with PDF as an attachment. Now the issue is the PDF does not previewed in the default preview option and getting a message in the preview window as given below but never rendered. But the PDF can be downloaded and viewed through Adobe acrobat without an issue. What could be the issue? Please suggest. The same worked 2 weeks ago but now it is not. Is that anything related to the file format? Experts any thoughts please.

[image]

**PDF preview with Processing File...**

[image]

**Code used to create the pdf attachment as a feed item:**

> The field in SFDC is PDF_Attachment__c which is long text field which
>   is used to store x-string value from SAP which is in hexadecimal
>   format. Sample value for the field PDF_Attachment__c is given below
>
> 255044462D312E330D0A25E2E3CFD30D0A25525354585044463320506172616D65746572733A0D0A322030206F626A0D0A3C3C0D0A2F54797065202F466F6E74

```
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
        feedItemInput.body = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();

        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput2 = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        messageInput2.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment1 = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment1.text = sob.Message__c+ '\n\n';
        messageInput2.messageSegments.add(textSegment1);

        textSegment1 = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment1.text = 'View Customer Details: ';
        messageInput2.messageSegments.add(textSegment1);    

        ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput linkSegment2 = new ConnectApi.LinkSegmentInput();
        linkSegment2.url = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/0019000000le1R8';
        messageInput2.messageSegments.add(linkSegment2);


        // Create text segment to hold the message body
        feedItemInput.body = messageInput2;

        // Create the canvas attachment
        ConnectApi.CanvasAttachmentInput attachmentInput = new ConnectApi.CanvasAttachmentInput();
        attachmentInput.developerName = 'Webdynpro_with_BSP';
        attachmentInput.title = 'Release Sales Order';
        attachmentInput.description = '';//strDesc;
        attachmentInput.thumbnailUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/logos/Apps/SAP/logo.png';
        attachmentInput.parameters = '{"OrdNo":"'+OrdNo+'"}';    
        attachmentInput.height = '400px';
        feedItemInput.attachment = attachmentInput;


        //Create FeedItemPost//
        ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItemobj = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, 
                                                                            ConnectApi.FeedType.RECORD, 
                                                                            Userinfo.getUserId(), 
                                                                            feedItemInput, 
                                                                            null);


        sob.IsFeedCreated__c = True;
        sob.FeedItemId__c = feedItemobj.Id;

        //**************************Create PDF Attachment*******************************************
        ConnectApi.BinaryInput bi = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(sob.PDF_Attachment__c), 'pdf', 'SalesOrder.pdf');

        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();


        ConnectApi.NewFileAttachmentInput cai = new ConnectApi.NewFileAttachmentInput();
        cai.title = 'Sales Document '+sob.Context_1__c;

        //Create new Feed Item Input and then post to Feed in Target Object  
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
        input.body = messageInput;
        input.attachment = cai;

        //The third param is the Record Id of the object you want to post to
        //The fifth is the binary input that adds the attachment
        ConnectApi.FeedItem fi = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '00590000002NtHH', input, bi);
```